# Why is my tabset tag coming up as unknown

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am currently trying to create a set of tabs using the 'tabset' tag with ui-bootstrap-0.9.0.min.js but eclipse keeps marking it as an unknown tab.  When I launch the page on my browser all I get is {{tabcontent}}.  Below is how I have called upon the bootstrap script along with how I am calling upon the tabset tag.  What am I doing wrong?

```
    <script src="jscripts/js/ui-bootstrap-0.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.16/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="jscripts/profile.js"></script>


    <tabset>
            <tab ng-repeat="tab in tabs" heading="{{tab.title}}" active="tab.active" disabled="tab.disabled">{{tab.content}}</tab>
        </tabset>
```

Comment: do you have a `ng-app`?

Comment: And where is 'tabs' stored?  Is it on a controller somewhere?

Comment: I have an data-ng-app="agentOnlineApp" located in the <html> tag.  My tabs are located in my profile.js file.  The Tabset tag is surrounded by a div tag that contains the data-ng-controller="TabControl"

Comment: Don't you get a javascript error?

Comment: No, it just marks the tag as unknown and when run in a browser just displays {{tab.content}}

Comment: I recently asked another question and was able to get it fixed.  When I reloaded the page it gave me an error that is related to this question.  I got a 404 error for the tab template and tabset template.  Do I need to download the template version of the ui.bootstrap instead of the one I currently have?

Comment: Apparently I do.  I gave it a shot and apparently the tpls version contains what I needed.

Comment: @Karson074 your `disabled="tab.disabled"` should be `disabled="{{tab.disabled}}"`

Answer (score 0):

Install `ngx-bootstrap`

```
npm i ngx-bootstrap
```

import `TabsModule` in your module i.e. `app.module.ts`

```
import { TabsModule } from "ngx-bootstrap/tabs";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    // ...
    TabsModule
    // ...
  ]
})
export class ProjectsModule { }
```